# Is there language support (highlighting, linting, formatting) for Standard ML for VSCode?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode and would like to have language support for Standard ML. The one extension that pops up on the extension marketplace did not work for me because it had the error

```
Cannot find "sml.json" in "/Users/douira/Documents/smltest"
```

and there is absolutely no documentation on this unmaintained extension. The repository for it returns a 404. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick: `To use this in your own programs, you really only need the sml-json.sml file.` from https://github.com/standardml/SML-JSON/blob/d6318d3423f5681309dcc24fed51de7f7d5a7603/README#L14

Comment: and how does this file provide language support in my IDE?

Comment: Will get back to you soon as I figure it out. Still setting up myself. Having said, once you have that file in your project, it generates a file used by the compiler, apparently. Will update you.

Comment: Got it working with https://github.com/stonebuddha/vscode-better-sml and then adding `  "[sml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "stonebuddha.vscode-better-sml"
  },```` to settings.json in vscode. Hope that helps.